# Upload multiple files from multiple inputs fields CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need your help in this code.
in my view i gave the user to add input fields dynamically by javascript code which is working properly

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile[]" id="DocumentFileName" multiple>
```

and in my controller i write this code to make the uploading

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$files = $_FILES;
$count = count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)
{
  if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i])
  {

    $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];  

    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
    $this->upload->do_upload();

    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $filename = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

    $data= array(
            'EmployeeID' => $EmployeeID,
            'DocumentTypeID' => $_POST['DocumentTypeID'][$i],
            'DocumentFileName' => $filename,
            'DocumentExpiryDate' => $_POST['DocumentExpiryDate'][$i]
            );
    $this->db->insert('employees_documents',$data); 

  }else{}
}
```

this code worked properly for one time only and uploaded all the files i gave to it but in the next times it uploads only one file from all selected files and also saved only one file from all selected

any idea of where is the wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: just a suggestion, take all uploaded images filename array and save it to a temparory folder and then after successfully uploading you can move or make it to the real directory and then insert all file name in the database.

Comment: and where is the config array?